# "Target class [app\Http\Controllers\WebScraper] does not exist.", but it does exist

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I can´t find the mistake that causes this error message. I tried everything from renaming it to deleting and creating it again but I just can´t find the mistake. Please help me! Thanks!

Controller("WebScraper"):

```
        <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WebScraper extends Controller
{
    public function games(){
        include('simple_html_dom.php');
        
        $day = 1; //temporär

        $html = file_get_html('https://sport.sky.de/bundesliga-spielplan-ergebnisse-'.$day);

        echo $html-> find('title', 0)->plaintext;

        $list = $html -> find('div[class="sdc-site-fixres-wrap"]', 0);

        $list_array = $list -> find('div');

        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list_array); $i++){
            echo $list_array[$i]->plaintext;
            echo "<br>";
        }

        return view('home.blade.php');
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use app\Http\Controllers\WebScraper;

Route::get('/', [WebScraper::class, 'games']);
```

Comment: `namespace App\Http\Controllers`, `use app\Http\Controllers\WebScraper` - now which is it, `App` or `app`?

Answer (score 1):

In routes
You should use App\Http\Controllers\WebScraper;

instead of app\Http\Controllers\WebScraper;

Comment: thnak you so much. I would have got severe depression for sure